# GWT-Export the client side code to a runnable file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

This is my first question here, so please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.

I'm currently learning GWT and I was wondering if I can make a web page which requires no Server. My code is working and if I run it out of Eclipse and test it in Chrome, it works fine. But how can I Export my client side Code with the css-rules etc. to a file which I can open (without a server)?

I hope you understand my question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care that you dont have any code in your `server` package, then right click in eclipse on your project -> google -> gwt compile
after compiling check out the `war` folder in your project and open the `*.html` file in a browser

Comment: Thank You it worked :)   - today i added some server code so i don't need this anymore for my current project but maybe in the future